# PowerShell: get values of json object

Tags: windows, powershell

Consider this json file(TESTKill.json):

```
{
    "CLT_PROD": {
        "CLRDIR": "C:\\Test",
        "CLREXE": "notepad.exe"
    },
    "CLT_PROD_GHOST": {
        "CLRDIR": "C:\\Kontrolle",
        "CLREXE": "powershell.exe"
    },
    "CLTc_PROD_Test1": {
        "CLRDIR": "D:\\Kontrolle",
        "CLREXE": "powershell.exe"
    },
    "CLT_PROD_Test2_GHOST": {
        "CLRDIR": "F:\\Kontrolle",
        "CLREXE": "powershell.exe"
    },
    "CLT_PROD_Test3_GHOST": {
        "CLRDIR": "J:\\ABU",
        "CLREXE": "powershell.exe"
    }
}
```

I want to give only the object names(CLT_PROD, CLT_PROD_GHOST, etc.) in a dropdown list in the GUI. I have the following code for this purpose:

```
$CLRJson = Get-Content -Raw -Path "C:\Temp\TESTKill.json" | ConvertFrom-Json
$CLRObjects = $CLRJson.psobject.Properties.name #select only the object names.

$objDropDownDBSchma = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$objDropDownDBSchma.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(40,40)
$objDropDownDBSchma.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,20)
$objForm.Controls.Add($objDropDownDBSchma)
#Objekte aus der json-Datei in die DropDown Liste hinzufügen
Foreach ($CLRObjekte in $CLRObjects) {
    $objDropDownDBSchma.items.Add($CLRObjekte) 
}
```

It works till here. I can select one object from the dropdown menu. The thing I want to have now is, after i choosed one object, i want to click a button and as a result, i should be able to get the values of the two variables "CLRDIR" & "CLREXE" of the appropriate object. For instance: if i had chosen the object "CLT_PROD_GHOST", i want to show the the value of those variables of this object in a text box. I don't know, how to script this. Anyone got any Idea ?

Thx for your help:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You read the value of the selected item from the dropdown menu.
This will give the name of the property you want to access. Then `powershell` can dynamically access the property from `$CLRJson`.
I don't remember exactly how to access the selected item of the drowdown menu.
You have also to register a scriptblock in the `OnClick` event handler for the `Button` you speak about that may contain something like this:

```
$name = $objDropDownDBSchma.SelectedItem.Value
$CLRObj = $CLRJson.$name
Write-Host $CLRObj.CLRDIR
Write-Host $CLRObj.CLREXE
```

Comment: thank you. This is exactly what i was doing. However, i wrote the variable name wrong. That's why it did not work. Now i got it. Thx man...